# ngClick behaves differently on localhost

Tags: angularjs

I have the following within an ngRepeat. Basically there is a dummy link that when clicked should change a class on another part of the block (making it visible). On my development server this works fine, but when I move the code to openshift the links propagate and cause a page refresh and change the URL to `.../#`. I expect I can use the `span` approach now commented out but I think that is bad practise for accessibility.

```
<p class="comment">
    {{r.comment}}
    <!-- <span class="more" ng-click="list.open[$index] = !list.open[$index]">...more&nbsp;info</span> -->
    <a href="#" class="more" ng-click="list.open[$index] = !list.open[$index]">...more&nbsp;info</a>
</p>
<div class='resto_meta_more' ng-class="{'closed':!list.open[$index]}">
    <p>{{r.address}}, {{r.link}}, {{r.blog}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
<a href="#"
```

by

```
<a href=""
```

From [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/a):

> a
>
> directive in module ng
>
> Modifies the default behavior of the html A tag so that the default action is prevented when the href attribute is empty.

Comment: OK, that worked, but does not explain why the # was OK on my development server

Comment: We can even skip the *href* attribute.

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess in your local? Or have you enabled the HTML5 History API?